# ARCore + Unity: Setting PlaneFindingMode on the SessionConfig is having no effect on plane detection

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

In my AR app I want some content only placeable on walls & some on floors. I attempted to achieve this by setting the PlaneFindingMode on the ARCoreSessionConfig object assigned to the session, & then resetting the session, but whatever option I choose the app will still detect both horizontal & vertical surfaces.

```
public void SetVertical(bool vertical)
{
    if (vertical)
    {
        config.PlaneFindingMode = DetectedPlaneFindingMode.Vertical;
    }
    else
    {
        config.PlaneFindingMode = DetectedPlaneFindingMode.Horizontal;
    }

    StartCoroutine(ResetSession());
}

private IEnumerator ResetSession()
{
    ARCoreSession session = goARCoreDevice.GetComponent<ARCoreSession>();
    ARCoreSessionConfig myConfig = session.SessionConfig;

    DestroyImmediate(session);

    yield return null;

    session = goARCoreDevice.AddComponent<ARCoreSession>();
    session.SessionConfig = myConfig;
    session.enabled = true;
}
```

I have also found that even when I remove this code & set the PlaneFindingMode manually, the same result occurs. Even if I set PlaneFindingMode to disabled, it will still find planes on walls & floors.

The config is definitely assigned to the session, so I'm not sure where else to look. Am I missing something else here?

Comment: Are you using instant preview? Because you can not disable plane finding in Instant preview.

Comment: No, I'm building the app onto the device

Comment: That is really strange then. What does it log if you do `Debug.Log(session.SessionConfig.PlaneFindingMode)` after you enabled the new Session

Comment: It logs either Horizontal or Vertical correctly